# Multiple column in IN() clause with zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

Is it possible to do this sort of query in zend frameowrk?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `relations` 
WHERE (root_type, root_id) IN ( ("PRJ", 12), ("PRJ", 13), ("GRP", 42))
```

I only found a way to make a query with a IN clause on one column but not on two columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` them instead, like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM relations r
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 'PRJ' AS root_typ, 12 AS root_id
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'PRJ',             13
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'GRP',             42
) AS t  ON r.root_type = t.root_type
       AND r.root_id   = t.root_id;
```

Comment: wow, that's a tricky one:) Any idea how to write such a request in zend?

Comment: @Tagazok - Sorry I don't know about zend. But I thought it might be helpful to share this. Try to write it as a normal `JOIN` like what you do a normal join in zend. Also try to execute it as a normal SQL if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [ZF1 query using Zend_Db_Statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html):

```
//common way to aquire currently selected db adapter
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
//$db is the currently selected database adapter.
$stmt = $db->query(
            SELECT * FROM `relations` 
            WHERE (root_type, root_id) 
            IN ( ("PRJ", 12), ("PRJ", 13), ("GRP", 42))
            );
```

This answer is not intended to be snide. For complex database queries, `Zend_Db_Statement` is often the *easiest/simplest/best* way to perform the query.

If you would like an explanation more tailored to your needs, please provide more info on your structure. In Zend Framework (1 or 2) there are often many ways to accomplish any given task.